# Use kwargs in a function when it contains arguments not-used by the function

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Say I have the following function:

```py
def sub1(a,b,foo="bar"):
    print(a+b)
    print(foo)

def main(*args,**kwargs):
    a,b = args
    sub1(a,b,**kwargs)
```

I can do

```py
main(2,3) #5, bar
main(2,3,foo="baz") #5, baz
```

which works fine.

But say I have parse an additioanl keyword-argument like

```py
main(2,3,qux="baz") #TypeError: sub1() got an unexpected keyword argument 'qux'
```

Why would we do this? Say I have an additional function which shares some of the arguments with `sub1` but also have some arguments that are different

```py
def sub2(foo,qux="fred"):
    print(foo)
    print(f"Hello {qux}")
```

then instead of having to do

```py
def main(*args,**sub1kwargs,**sub2kwargs):
   sub1(**sub1kwargs)
   sub2(**sub2kwargs)
```

we could just parse the same `kwargs` around and the function just takes what it needs:

```py
def main(*args,**kwargs):
    sub1(**kwargs)
    sub2(**kwargs)
```

Of course we could just loop over the parameter-list before parsing the parameters to `sub1`, (or use `foo = kwargs.get("foo","bar)` in `sub1`) but I want to know, if we can avoid doing so and have only one `kwargs`?

Comment: From readability's *PoV* (and most likely, later from debuging's) this kind of looks like a mess.

Comment: Yeah, it might be, but how I'm using it, it actually doesn't (I wouldn't bother you by providing 8 scripts and a wrapper to explain why I want that specific solution)

Comment: I know that sometimes there are some constraints (worked with legacy code as well), I was just saying... the right way would be to refactor those functions but often it simply doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: Totally agree on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, just add kwargs to sub1 and it will auto-parse any named arguments you provided, and the rest will be put into kwargs:

```
def sub1(a, b, foo="bar", **kwargs):
```

That way you can still call sub1 with or without foo, but you can also call it with or without other arguments without causing an error.

```
main(1, 2, foo="hello")
  > 1, 2, "hello"
main(1, 2, qux="hello")
  > 1, 2, "bar"
```

Comment: Aaah... of course!

Comment: So the advice is to  accept utterly useless unused `kwargs` just so any calling code can just dump their trash!? I think I would fire any junior submitting code like that :D

Comment: I did not ask if it was the best way to do, or how to optimize it, but I asked if it could be done, which QuantumMecha provides a solution for. Note, that the actual problem might be different from the functions defined above (spoiler; it is)

Comment: @CutePoison stop interfering with SO's *manufactured indignation program!* It's the only thing that gets some people through their day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[*"Explicit is better than implicit."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2)

There is nothing really to be gained from passing anonymous `kwargs` around. Functions should really name their keyword arguments whenever possible. And callers such as your `main` do not improve in quality or readability by saving the odd byte of code. Process/filter the kwargs where needed. Either

```
def main(*args, foo="bar", qux="baz"):
    sub1(*args, foo=foo)
    sub2(qux=qux)
```

or

```
def main(*args, **kwargs):
    sub1(*args, foo=kwargs.get("foo"))
    sub2(qux=kwargs.get("qux"))
```

will do the job and be easily understood.

Of course, you can define a function like (do **NOT**):

```
def sub1(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(a+b)
    print(kwargs.get("foo", "bar"))
```

This will allow callers to pass random kwargs that will be ignored, but it makes it much harder for the caller to find out what kwargs are really needed by this function.

Comment: It depends on the usage of `kwargs` and how the functions are written tbh. With the example above, of course it is not optimal, but they do only serve the purpose of an example